# An error with an sql string (c#)

Tags: c#, sql, string

I have written the following script (in c#):

```
string     sqlCommand = "SELECT   * " +
                 "FROM     tblMatches " +
                 "WHERE matchPlayerNick =" + comboBoxPlayer.Text + " " +
                 "ORDER BY matchName ";
```

When I run my program, I get this: "data type mismatch in the criteria experssion".
the datatype of matchPlayer is, of course, "text".

what's wrong with the script then?

thanks!

Comment: a lot is quite wrong with this.  Please google sql injection...  But what you are looking for is the lack of single quotes surrounding your text field.

Comment: You should look into parameterized queries.

Comment: injection attack, injection attack, injection attack. If I type `; DELETE tblMatches; GO` in the combo box, you may have issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string     sqlCommand = "SELECT   * " +
                 "FROM     tblMatches " +
                 "WHERE matchPlayerNick ='" + comboBoxPlayer.Text + "' " +
                 "ORDER BY matchName ";
```

but the query above is vulnerable with `sql injection`. It can be prevented if you parameterized the values using `Command Object and Parameters`.

Try this code snippet:

```
string content = comboBoxPlayer.Text;
string connStr = "connection string here";
string sqlCommand = @"SELECT   *
                      FROM     tblMatches 
                      WHERE matchPlayerNick = @content
                      ORDER BY matchName";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            // other codes here
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // do not hide it
            // e.Message.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

For proper coding

- use `using` statement for propr object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle objects

Comment: @Idan you're welcome. Even if the value you are passing contains single quotes, it doesn't break the string.

Answer (score 4):

You've forgotten the quotes.
Using parameterized queries, it's a good practice.